# VS "Send Query to Outlook" does not work if VS is running as administrator and outlook is not

Tags: windows, visual-studio, outlook, administrator

Now, you might think that running outlook as administrator fixes the problem, and it does.... sort of.  The problem is, once outlook is running as administrator, it can no longer launch links in your browser!  Talk about chain reaction!

Is there any way to just make everything run as administrator?  I think I need VS to run as admin because what I am developing requires admin rights to run...

Answer (score 0):

Disable UAC on your system. If you do this then *all* processes launched by a member of the Administrators group on your system will be run with full administrative rights by default (like XP and previous).